# Getting profile information from tfs REST API showing Page not found

Tags: rest, tfs, tfs-2015

Am sure this might have been asked before.I have searched like anything not getting any information thats why i thought of posting here. any help is appreciated

https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=1.0

this REST API always giving Page not found tfs2015 server using.

Comment: can any one please help me on this. is there any settings needs to be done on Tfs for this REST api to alive ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The REST API you mentioned is for VSTS :

```
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=1.0
```

For on-premise TFS (TFS 2015 in your case), you can use below REST API to get the profile information (connect to TFS first):

```
http://server:8080/tfs/_api/_common/GetUserProfile?__v=5
```

Comment: This works great, but is there any documentation for the on-premise TFS REST API? Searches always lead me to the VSTS documentation, and several of those functions just work identically, but it would be nice to really understand the differences.