# TFS - API page not found

Tags: rest, tfs

I am trying to acces some source files. I need to get a list of the files to acces. I would like to use the CodeSearch function of the TFS Rest API. All I get is a page not found error.

I have searched all over the internet for TFS 2017 API documentation, but I always end up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1), I can not find any TFS 2017 - specific documentation.

I think its similar problem to what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325523/getting-profile-information-from-tfs-rest-api-showing-page-not-found) question was about.

I am successfully retrieving the source code by sending a GET request on to

**.eu/Development/_apis/tfvc/items?path=%24%2FProjectName%2FFileName%2FMain%2SubFolder%2FGetRandomArticle.cs**

but when I try to send a POST request on to

**.eu/Development/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=4.1-preview.1**

I get a 401 "Page not found."

This is thetest request body:

```
{
     "searchText": "IEnumerable",
     "$skip": 0,
     "$top": 1,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=vsts), the version 4.1-preview1 of the REST API is not present in TFS 2017. Thus, the behavior you're observing might be because the incorrect version of the API is used. Try switching to 3.0 and try again.

If you follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1#where-are-the-earlier-versions-of-rest-apis-before-41), you'll find out how to explore the pre-4.1 REST API.

Comment: You are right. I this was just me learning the tfs api and being confused about their documentation. Now it makes finally sense to me. Thank you. My problem was that I did not know about their backwards api version compatibility. That the old endpoints are viable for the new version. So they let you pick at the "get started with vsts rest api" page from 2 options. 4.1 and 5. But the apis are all mixed together because of their compatibility with the newest version. I  haven't seen "Documentation for API V3.0" heading anywhere. Also, some links from their github help page return 404.

Comment: That very page you referenced in your question contains the link to the pre-4.1 API documentation. Switch to the `TFS 2017` in the upper left corner, and you'll get the APIs compatible with your environment.